# SparkOutOfMemoryError while loading in the s3 bucket

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql, out-of-memory

I have a dataframe and writing into S3 bucket target location. In the code Coalesce is using for loading data and getting SparkOutOfMemoryError.The current code which is having Coalesce been using multiple projects, And seen lot of solutions recommended repartition and it worked for me. Even it has zero records, coalesce is not working.
Is there any other-way to resolve this issue without changing to repartition?

**code:**

```
empsql = 'Select * From Employee'
df = spark.sql(empsql) ##Spark is configured
df.coalesce(2).write.mode('overwrite').format("parquet").option("delimiter",'|').save(s3_path, header = True)
```

**Error:**

> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows.  at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply
>     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask    at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run   at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply   at
>   org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally   at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run
>       Caused by: org.apache.spark.memory.SparkOutOfMemoryError: Unable to acquire 44 bytes of memory, got 0     at
>   org.apache.spark.memory.MemoryConsumer.throwOom(MemoryConsumer.java:)
>     at org.apache.spark.memory.MemoryConsumer.allocatePage  at
>   org.apache.spark.util.collection.unsafe.sort.UnsafeExternalSorter.acquireNewPageIfNecessary(UnsafeExternalSorter.java:383)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.util.collection.unsafe.sort.UnsafeExternalSorter.insertRecord(UnsafeExternalSorter.java:407)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.UnsafeExternalRowSorter.insertRow(UnsafeExternalRowSorter.java:135)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage29.sort_addToSorter_0$(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage29.processNext(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$11$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:619)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.RowIteratorFromScala.advanceNext(RowIterator.scala:83)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.ZippedPartitionsRDD2.compute(ZippedPartitionsRDD.scala:89)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.CoalescedRDD$$anonfun$compute$1.apply(CoalescedRDD.scala:100)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.CoalescedRDD$$anonfun$compute$1.apply(CoalescedRDD.scala:99)
>     at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:435)   at
>   scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:441)    at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:239)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1394)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:245)

Comment: Can we see the Spark UI stages tab? Maybe that will give us more information.

Comment: you could verify your executor configuration and also check in spark UI if there is any data skew which could be causing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

No sure  if this will work for you but try doing this

```
df.coalesce(2,shuffle=true).write.mode('overwrite').format("parquet").option("delimiter",'|').save(s3_path, header = True)
```

shuflle =true  will add a shuffle step.Partitions would execute in parallel. The behaviour is similar to using repartition

Comment: does it work with coalesce with more than 10 like coalesce(11)?

Comment: I think it cannot increase partition number more than actual partition number. instead use repartition function.

Comment: coalesce --  pros --decreases partition , with minimal shuffle , does not create equi sized partitions . works best if the difference is small between the actual partition number to desired partition number ,  will  not ignore existing partitions

repartition --   increases or decreases the num partition , tends to create equi sized partition, best utilizes the parallelism (which can  be a boon for prod releases  ),will ignore existing partitions and create new one

Answer (score 0):

I solve my issue by adding repartition(key) by well-distributed key before coalesce().
I think it helps Spark allow to send preordered data to the writer node and not to do sorting on writer executor.